# How to set privilege to wordpress subscriber for private page

Tags: user-access, private, privileges

I am having private page.I want to show this page only when "subscriber" logged in."Editor" should not access this page.How can i set the privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a plugin something like this should work

```
    //functions.php
    function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return $user_role;
    }

    //page template
    $role = get_user_role();
    if($role == "subscriber"){
       //cool you can see this
    }
    else {
       //sorry not allowed
    }
```

A BETTER way would be to use something like the [Members Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) which lets you have custom roles and check roles and such.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a couple years old, but I thought I'd provide a simpler, cleaner conditional:

```
if (current_user_can('subscriber')) {

// subscriber code

} else {

// non-subscriber code

}
```

Comment: Please explain "as of WP 3.5.2"? What is new about `current_user_can`?

Comment: As of v3.5.2, which is the version I'm currently using when I posted my answer, this conditional answers the OP question in a much cleaner/simpler way than the accepted answer. How is that not clear?

Comment: `current_user_can` is not new in 3.5.2. It has been around since 2.0.0, according to a note in the source. Your answer implies that this works _beginning with_ -- aka, "as of"-- WordPress 3.5.2. That is not accurate.

Comment: "As of" does not imply _beginning with_... Please don't argue with me about semantics of the English language. 

Nor did I say `current_user_can` is a new function. Please also stop arguing with me about the intent of my answer.

Comment: I am not arguing about the _intent_ of your answer but [I found the language of your answer to be confusing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of), so I asked a question, then, as you didn't understand the confusion, I explained why. Simple process. Not really something worth the hostility.